# python download of zip file by url - downloads currupt file

Tags: python, url, download, zip

I am trying to download a zip file from URL with a python script
the zip file is downloaded, but can't be opened since it's corrupted.

This is my script:

```
zipUrl = "https://data.gov.il/dataset/dff8a168-af6c-4e0f-bbe3-c4bd3646084c/resource/c68b4df6-c809-4bb5-a546-61fa1528fed5/download/parcel_all.zip"
targetFile = "parcel_all_from_web.zip"

import requests
try:
    r = requests.get(zipUrl)
    with open(targetFile, 'wb') as f:
        for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
            if chunk: # filter out keep-alive new chunks
                f.write(chunk)

except:
    print("error in download")
```